# Tasks for mobile devices on Toloka

Tags: mobile, toloka

I am creating a task on Toloka that performers will complete on a mobile device. How do I use a web browser to see what a task looks like on a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Open the console in your browser (press F12 or right-click "Explore item"). In the upper-right panel, click the mobile phone icon. In the menu bar at the top of the page, you can change the mobile phone model and see what your task looks like on screens with different resolutions.

In case of any mobile specifics (like taking photos or checking location), you may ask Toloka customer support to send you a special Android app build for the Toloka Sandbox environment.